# Using JavaScript to create custom welcome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

I am using a script in a SharePoint content editor web part (CEWP) that welcomes the user to the site based on name and time of day and then has another link as well.  I am having issues with formatting it.  I have customzed my working script but for some reason the font size and color has not worked properly.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I think it has to do with my 'var WelcomeMenuContent' but am not sure.

Any help is appreciated as always:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://wss.companyabc.org/sites/WSS001905/SiteAssets/Libraries/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#Header {
font-family: Arial;
color: #cc0717;
font-size: 3em;
text-decoration: underline;
}
#SubHeader {
font-family: Arial;
color:#000000;
font-size: 1.5em;
}
#Hyperlink{
font-family: Arial;
color:#cc0717;
weight: bold;
font-size: 1em;
}
</style>

<center>
<div class="Header">
<span id="greeting">Hello</span>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var WelcomeMenuContent = $('.ms-welcomeMenu > a.ms-menu-a > span');
        var UserName = WelcomeMenuContent.text();
        var FirstName = UserName.split(" ")[0];
        var Display;
        var Digital = new Date()
        var Hours = Digital.getHours()

        Morning = 'Good morning' + " " + FirstName;
        Lunch = 'Good afternoon' + " " + FirstName;
        Evening = 'Good evening' + " " + FirstName;
        Night = 'Good night' + " " + FirstName;
        TimeElse = 'Welcome' + " " + FirstName;

            if (Hours >= 5 && Hours <= 11) 
                document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML=(Morning);
                    else if (Hours >= 12 && Hours <= 17) 
                document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML=(Lunch);
                    else if (Hours >= 18 && Hours <= 22) 
                document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML=(Evening);
                    else if (Hours >= 23 && Hours <= 4) 
                document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML=(Night);
            else
                document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML=(TimeElse);
    }); 
</script>
</div>
    <div class="SubHeader">
        <span>Welcome to the home of Company ABC</span>
    </div>
</br>
<hr>
</br>
    <div class="Hyperlink">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Click here to continue to the  Community SharePoint Site</a>
    </div>
<hr>
</br>

</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ID to address classes. In CSS, `#` addresses id attributes, whearas `.` addresses class attributes. Change the following:

```
#Header      >>    >> .Header 
#SubHeader   >> to >> .SubHeader
#Hyperlink   >>    >> .Hyperlink
```

Just a note, as you are already using jQuery, consider changing

```
 document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML=(Morning);
```

to

```
 $('#greeting').text(Morning);
```

Comment: Css dupes me again!  Thank you very much.  I attempted a test with the $ object:

    else if (Hours >= 12 && Hours <= 17) 
    $("greeting").text(Lunch);

But it just gives me the catch all 'Hello' text.  Am I missing something? Maybe ('Lunch')?  Thank you again

Comment: `$('#greeting')`, not `$('greeting')`. `#` looks for IDs, no hash looks for HTML tag names.

Answer (score 0):

FYI Bamboo solutions has a free webpart that handles customized greetings, though it may not be as robust as what you are trying to code:

**Hello WebPart**
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/c-1-helper-web-part.aspx